# Solving linter error no-undef for document

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am using `airbnb` extension for linting my React Project. Now, in my `index.js` I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

linter says:

```
no-undef 'document' is not defined.at line 8 col 3
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve/get around this. The two key ways are to either specify `document` as `global` or to set the `eslint-env` as `browser` (what you probably want). You can do this 1) in-file, 2) in the configuration, or even 3) when running from the CLI.

1) In-file:

1. Set the environment as `browser` in your file:

   ```
   /* eslint-env browser */
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import App from './App';

   ReactDOM.render(
     <App />,
     document.getElementById('root'),
   );
   ```
2. Add it as a global in the file itself:

   ```
   /* global document */
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import App from './App';

   ReactDOM.render(
     <App />,
     document.getElementById('root'),
   );
   ```

2) In the eslint configuration:

1. Set the environment as `browser` in the configuration:

   ```
   {
     "env": {
       "browser": true,
       "node": true
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add it as a global in the configuration:

   ```
   {
     "globals": {
       "document": false
     }
   }
   ```

3) From the CLI:

1. Using env: `eslint --env browser,node file.js`
2. Using globals: `eslint --global document file.js`

Resources:
[Specifying Globals with ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals)
[Specifying Environments with ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)
[Specifying env with ESLint CLI](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--env)
[Specifying globals with ESLint CLI](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--global)