# Why is document not working on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've looked at various websites but non have helped. To me everything seems to be correct, but I can't get the

```
document.getElementByClassName("first").style.display="none";
```

to work no matter how many times I tried, I kept getting the same error message on JS;

> ERROR:'document' is not defined.[no-undef]

Tried defining the 'document' part and didn't help. Maybe, I was doing the connection between external folders incorrect I tried that and nothing changed

HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
       <script src="JS.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="first">
    <p>Hello and welcome to my first page<br>
    in this page I will test out new think<br>
    and see what works and what doesn't<br>
    </p>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("first").style.display="none";
```

The button is suppose to clear all he style's from "first".I've changed many outcomes and have nothing happen to the code just the same error repeating its-self over and over again.

Comment: `onclick="myFunction()"`

Comment: If nothing else works, make sure you have `display: block` defined in your `.first` class before you begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that the error you are recieving comes from a linter, but has nothing to do with your code not working. To fix your linter issue, you might want to have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858052/solving-linter-error-no-undef-for-document).
For errors that are produced at runtime, you should have a look at your browser console (In most cases opened with **F12**).

In regards to your main issue, there are two things to fix:

**1)**
Your inline onclick handler should be called like so:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

**2)**
Instead of using *document.getElementsByClassName()* - which returns an array -
I recommend you to use *document.querySelector()* instead, as it returns just the first element it found and is much easier to use, if you are already familiar with css selectors.
For more information an the querySelector-function have a look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

So, in your code it should look like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector(".first").style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`document.getElementByClassName()` returns an array of elements, so you'll need the index of the element you want to target.

You should call the function by `myFunction()` and add `[0]` to `getElementsByClassName` to get specific element.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0].style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
       <script src="JS.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="first">
    <p>Hello and welcome to my first page<br>
    in this page I will test out new think<br>
    and see what works and what doesn't<br>
    </p>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```